# Android Room + Kotlin pattern

Tags: kotlin, android-room

the Android Room documentation says that we should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object.

I was thinking about it, and I would like to know if its recommended to put the AppDatabase class inside my Application class. Or if I can use the Kotlin singleton for that.

Let's say I have a DAO called CarroDAO and class CarrosDatabase that is a RoomDatabase.

Is it ok to create a DatabaseManager class using a Kotlin object/singleton ?

```
object DatabaseManager {
    private var dbInstance: CarrosDatabase

    init {
        val appContext = MyApplication.getInstance().applicationContext

        dbInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                appContext,
                CarrosDatabase::class.java,
                "mybd.sqlite")
                .build()
    }

    fun getCarroDAO(): CarroDAO {
        return dbInstance.carroDAO()
    }
}
```

So I can get the DAO class like this:

```
val dao = DatabaseManager.getCarroDAO()
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a dependency injection framework for handling singletons for you. Like this you're able to control the life-time of the instances.

Comment: This is a design question, not a code question. Looks like you are well aware of how to create a singleton and what the alternatives are. The question of whether or not using a singleton is a good idea is pretty much out of scope for SO.

Answer (score 2):

According to Android documentation, we can create a database instance using the singleton design pattern  as follows
Create a room database entity

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey var uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") var firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") var lastName: String?
)
```

Create DAO class

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE:  first AND " +
           "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
```

Create database with singleton pattern

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(
            context: Context
        ): AppDatabase = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "database-name"
            ).build()
        }
    }
}
```

You can get database instance by following code

```
 var databaseInstance=AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
```